# Prevent comments_template() to load comments.php

Tags: templates

I'm developing a WordPress theme using a template engine. I want my code to be as much compatible as possible with WP core functionality.

### Some context first

My first problem was to find a way to *resolve* the template starting from a WP query. I solved that one using a library of mine, [Brain\Hierarchy](https://github.com/Brain-WP/Hierarchy).

Regarding `get_template_part()` and other functions that loads partials like `get_header()`, `get_footer()` and similar, it was pretty easy to write wrapper to template engine partial functionality.

### The issue

My problem is now how to load comments template.

WordPress function [`comments_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/) is a ~200 lines function that does a lot of things, which I want to do as well for maximum core compatibility.

However, as soon as I call `comments_template()`, a file is `require`d, it is the first of:

- the file in the constant `COMMENTS_TEMPLATE`, if defined
- `comments.php` in theme folder, if found
- `/theme-compat/comments.php` in WP includes folder as last resort fallback

In short, there's no way to prevent the function to load a PHP file, which is not desirable for me, because I need to *render* my templates and not simply use `require`.

### Current solution

At the moment, I'm shipping an empty `comments.php` file and I'm using [`'comments_template'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comments_template/) filter hook, to know which template WordPress wants to loads, and use feature from my template engine to load the template.

Something like this:

```
function engineCommentsTemplate($myEngine) {

    $toLoad = null; // this will hold the template path

    $tmplGetter = function($tmpl) use(&$toLoad) {
       $toLoad = $tmpl;

       return $tmpl;
    };

    // late priority to allow filters attached here to do their job
    add_filter('comments_template', $tmplGetter, PHP_INT_MAX);

    // this will load an empty comments.php file I ship in my theme
    comments_template();

    remove_filter('comments_template', $tmplGetter, PHP_INT_MAX);

    if (is_file($toLoad) && is_readable($toLoad)) {
       return $myEngine->render($toLoad);
    }

    return '';    
}
```

### The question

This works, is core compatible, but... is there a way to make it work without having to ship an empty `comments.php`?

Because I don't like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure the following solution is *better* than the solution in OP, let's just say is an alternative, probably more hackish, solution.

I think you can use a PHP exception to stop WordPress execution when `'comments_template'` filter is applied.

You can use a custom exception class as a DTO to *carry* the template.

This is a draft for the excepion:

```
class CommentsTemplateException extends \Exception {

   protected $template;

   public static function forTemplate($template) {
     $instance = new static();
     $instance->template = $template;

     return $instance;
   }

   public function template() {
      return $this->template;
   }
}
```

With this exception class available, your function becomes:

```
function engineCommentsTemplate($myEngine) {

    $filter = function($template) {
       throw CommentsTemplateException::forTemplate($template);
    };  

    try {
       add_filter('comments_template', $filter, PHP_INT_MAX); 
       // this will throw the excption that makes `catch` block run
       comments_template();
    } catch(CommentsTemplateException $e) {
       return $myEngine->render($e->template());
    } finally {
       remove_filter('comments_template', $filter, PHP_INT_MAX);
    }
}
```

The `finally` block requires PHP 5.5+.

Works the same way, and doesn't require an empty template.

Answer (score 4):

I have wrestled with this before and my solution was — it can knock itself out requiring file, as long as it doesn't *do* anything.

Here is relevant code from my [Meadow templating project](https://github.com/Rarst/meadow):

```
public function comments_template( \Twig_Environment $env, $context, $file = 'comments.twig', $separate_comments = false ) {

    try {
        $env->loadTemplate( $file );
    } catch ( \Twig_Error_Loader $e ) {
        ob_start();
        comments_template( '/comments.php', $separate_comments );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    add_filter( 'comments_template', array( $this, 'return_blank_template' ) );
    comments_template( '/comments.php', $separate_comments );
    remove_filter( 'comments_template', array( $this, 'return_blank_template' ) );

    return twig_include( $env, $context, $file );
}

public function return_blank_template() {

    return __DIR__ . '/blank.php';
}
```

I let `comments_template()` go through the motions to set up globals and such, but feed it empty PHP file to `require` and move on to my actual Twig template for output.

Note that this requires to be able to intercept initial `comments_template()` call, which I can do since my Twig template is calling intermediary abstraction rather than actual PHP function.

While I still have to ship empty file for it, I do so in library and implementing theme doesn't have to care about it at all.

Comment: Upvoted, thanks. I already saw your approach since I used Meadow before. What I did not like here is the fact that a blank template need to be shipped anyway. Moreover,  this breaks any attempt to use `comments_template` filter or `COMMENTS_TEMPLATE` constant to customize the template. Which is not pivotal, but, as I said, I wanted to stay as much as possible compatible with core.

Comment: @gmazzap hmmm... no reason I couldn't add support for filter & constant in my wrapper though, but it gets into micromanaging.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution: Use a temporary file – with a unique file name

After a lot of jumps and crawling into the dirtiest corners of PHP, I rephrased the question to just:

> How can one *trick* PHP into returning `TRUE` for `file_exists( $file )`?

as the code in core just is

```
file_exists( apply_filters( 'comments_template', $template ) )
```

Then the question was solved quicker:

```
$template = tempnam( __DIR__, '' );
```

and that's it. Maybe it would be better to use `wp_upload_dir()` instead:

```
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$template = tempname( $uploads['basedir'], '' );
```

Another option might be to use [`get_temp_dir()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_temp_dir/) which wraps `WP_TEMP_DIR`. Hint: It strangely falls back to `/tmp/` so files will *not* get preserved between reboots, which `/var/tmp/` would. One can do a simple string comparison at the end and check the return value and then fix this in case it's needed – which is not in this case:

```
$template = tempname( get_temp_dir(), '' )
```

Now to quickly test if there are errors thrown for a temporary file without contents:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$template = tempnam( __DIR__, '' );
var_dump( $template );
require $template;
```

And: **No Errors** → working.

**EDIT:** As **@toscho** pointed out in the comments, there's still a **better** way to do it:

```
$template = tempnam( trailingslashit( untrailingslashit( sys_get_temp_dir() ) ), 'comments.php' );
```

Note: According to [a users note on php.net docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php#80690), the `sys_get_temp_dir()` behavior differs between systems. Therefore the result gets the trailing slash removed, then added again. As the core bug [#22267](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22267) is fixed, this should work on Win/ IIS servers now as well.

Your refactored function (not tested):

```
function engineCommentsTemplate( $engine )
{
    $template = null;

    $tmplGetter = function( $original ) use( &$template ) {
        $template = $original;
        return tempnam( 
            trailingslashit( untrailingslashit( sys_get_temp_dir() ) ),
            'comments.php'
        );
    };

    add_filter( 'comments_template', $tmplGetter, PHP_INT_MAX );

    comments_template();

    remove_filter( 'comments_template', $tmplGetter, PHP_INT_MAX );

    if ( is_file( $template ) && is_readable( $template ) ) {
        return $engine->render( $template );
    }

    return '';
}
```

Bonus Nr.1: `tmpfile()` will return `NULL`. Yeah, really.

Bonus Nr.2: [`file_exists( __DIR__ )`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) will return `TRUE`. Yeah, really … in case you forgot.

<sup>^ This leads to an actual bug in WP core.</sup>

---

To help others going in explorer mode and finding those (badly to undocumented pieces), I will quickly sum up what I tried:

### Attempt 1: Temporary file in memory

The first attempt I made was to create a stream to a temporary file, using `php://temp`. From the PHP docs:

> The only difference between the two is that `php://memory` will always store its data in memory, whereas `php://temp` will use a temporary file once the amount of data stored hits a predefined limit (the default is 2 MB). The location of this temporary file is determined in the same way as the `sys_get_temp_dir()` function.

The code:

```
$handle = fopen( 'php://temp', 'r+' );
fwrite( $handle, 'foo' );
rewind( $handle );
var_dump( file_exist( stream_get_contents( $handle, 5 ) );
```

Finding: Nope, does not work.

### Attempt 2: Use a temporary file

There's `tmpfile()`, so why not use that?!

```
var_dump( file_exists( tmpfile() ) );
// boolean FALSE
```

Yeah, that much about this shortcut.

### Attempt 3: Use a custom stream wrapper

Next I thought I could [build a custom stream wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php) and [register it using `stream_wrapper_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php). Then I could use a *virtual template* from that stream to trick core into believing that we have a file. Example code below (I already deleted the full class and history does not have enough steps…)

```
class TemplateStreamWrapper
{
    public $context;

    public function stream_open( $path, $mode, $options, &$opened )
    {
        // return boolean
    }
}

stream_wrapper_register( 'vt://comments', 'TemplateStreamWrapper' );
// … etc. …
```

Again, this returned `NULL` on `file_exists()`.

---

Tested with PHP 5.6.20

Comment: I think that your Attempt 3 should work in theory.
In your custom stream wrapper, did you implement `stream_stat()`? I think that this is what `file_exists()` will call to make its check...
http://php.net/manual/en/streamwrapper.stream-stat.php

Comment: Upvoted because is quite nice and not very hackish. However, since my code is intended to be used in different setups, I'm afraid that writing permission could be an issue. Moreover, temporary files need to be deleted, which is not that easy *on the fly*, because it's not easy to intercept the full path returned by `tempnam()`. Using a cron job will work, but it's additional overhead...

Comment: I think writing temporary file is worse than shipping empty template. Fixed empty template will get cached into opcode. Temp file will have to be written to disk, cold-parsed (no opcode), then deleted. It's better to minimize disk hits for no good reason.

Comment: @Rarst The question never was _"what is better"_ performance wise. Question boiled down to not having the template file :)

Comment: @AlainSchlesser I added pretty much every method and simply `var_dump()`ed in it to see what gets triggered when. Will check that again as I did not yesterday because of storms history limit. Thanks!

Comment: `tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'comments.php' )` is written **once**, you can **reuse** the file name, and the file is **empty**, so it doesn't use many resources. Plus it is easy to understand in your code. By far the best solution, imho.

Comment: @toscho Edited the answer with your idea with a minor improvement.

Answer (score 3):

As [@AlainSchlesser](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/87576/alain-schlesser) suggested to follow the route (and as non working things always bug me), I retried building a stream wrapper for virtual files. I could not solve it (read: reading the return values on the docs) on my own, but solved it with the help of [@HPierce on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37553914/376483).

```
class VirtualTemplateWrapper
{
    public $context;

    public function stream_open( $path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path ) { return true; }

    public function stream_read( $count ) { return ''; }

    public function stream_eof() { return ''; }

    public function stream_stat() {
        # $user = posix_getpwuid( posix_geteuid() );
        $data = [
            'dev'     => 0,
            'ino'     => getmyinode(),
            'mode'    => 'r',
            'nlink'   => 0,
            'uid'     => getmyuid(),
            'gid'     => getmygid(),
            #'uid'     => $user['uid'],
            #'gid'     => $user['gid'],
            'rdev'    => 0,
            'size'    => 0,
            'atime'   => time(),
            'mtime'   => getlastmod(),
            'ctime'   => FALSE,
            'blksize' => 0,
            'blocks'  => 0,
        ];
        return array_merge( array_values( $data ), $data );
    }

    public function url_stat( $path, $flags ) {
        return $this->stream_stat();
    }
}
```

You just need to register the new class as new protocol:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    stream_wrapper_register( 'virtual', 'VirtualTemplateWrapper' );
}, 0 );
```

This then allows to create a *virtual* (non existing) file:

```
$template = fopen( "virtual://comments", 'r+' );
```

Your function can then get refactored to:

```
function engineCommentsTemplate( $engine )
{
    $replacement = null;
    $virtual = fopen( "virtual://comments", 'r+' );

    $tmplGetter = function( $original ) use( &$replacement, $virtual ) {
        $replacement = $original;
        return $virtual;
    };

    add_filter( 'comments_template', $tmplGetter, PHP_INT_MAX );

    comments_template();

    remove_filter( 'comments_template', $tmplGetter, PHP_INT_MAX );

    // As the PHP internals are quite unclear: Better safe then sorry
    unset( $virtual );

    if ( is_file( $replacement ) && is_readable( $replacement ) ) {
        return $engine->render( $replacement );
    }

    return '';
}
```

as the `file_exists()` check in core returns `TRUE` and the `require $file` throws no error.

I have to note that I am quite happy how this turned out as it might be really helpful with unit tests.

Comment: Great findings!  I like this approach best ;-) I'm sure there are other parts of the core that this could be applied to.

Comment: Upvoted and thanks! For unit tests there's already https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream so no need to reinvent the wheel ;) Btw, I like this approach, not sure I will use this because the exception method make me feel happily evil :D

Comment: @gmazzap I am very sure [this is how you looked when you found out](http://i.imgur.com/42tKVrt.gifv).

Comment: @kaiser nah, I found it because I RTFM :P https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mocking-the-filesystem