# Is it possible to completely stop WP_Query retrieving posts?

Tags: wp-query, hooks, cache

I'm trying to use [WP Redis](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-redis/) to cache entire [$wp_query](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/query.php) object with key is [$query_vars_hash](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1286).

This is how `$wp_query` was added to `$wp_object_cache`:

```
add_action('wp', function($wp)
{
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    global $wp_query;

    if ( !wp_cache_get($wp_query->query_vars_hash, 'globals') )
    {
        wp_cache_add($wp_query->query_vars_hash, $wp_query, 'globals');
    }
});
```

Then, I need to check if a query has already cached before `WP_Query` can retrieve posts:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query)
{
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    $cached_query = wp_cache_get($query->query_vars_hash, 'globals');

    if ($cached_query)
    {
        $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = &$cached_query;

        return; // Return immediately to prevent retrieving posts again.
    }
});
```

**Problem**:

`return` or `exit` doesn't work in this case. Then, `WP_Query` will still hit database to retrieve posts again.

**Question**:

Regardless of the plugin, is it possible to completely stop `WP_Query` retrieving posts?

Comment: I feel like the plugin should handle this... Are you sure you're going about this the right way? Have you asked about this on their forums? On their github issues?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee the plugin uses the same functionalities as default [WordPress caching API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache). The only difference is it helps connect to Redis server. Of course, I'm also trying to find the right way.

Comment: not sure why do you think that the query will not fire. returning from the action do not return by magic from the calling function

Comment: @MarkKaplun I also double about that but `return` might be the only command we can call in this case.

Comment: @Dan, I don't get what is that you assume, you obviously assume something which is not true, probably at the php level

Comment: @MarkKaplun Ah, how stupid am I :). Thank you for pointing out my mistake!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the moment, it is not possible.

When `'pre_get_posts'` runs, is too late to stop `WP_Query` to perform a query.

WordPress itself, when you try to query a taxonomy that does not exists, adds `AND (0 = 1)` to the `WHERE` clause of the SQL query, to ensure it returns no results very quickly...

There's a [trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36687) with a patch that will probably lands in core with WP 4.6, that introduces a new filter: `'posts_pre_query'`. Returning an array on that filter will make `WP_Query` stop processing and use the array provided as its posts array.

This could somehow helps you in implementing what you are trying to do.

Waiting fot this, anything you could do is somehow *hackish*, the *trick* core itself uses is quite hackish as well.

Recently, I'm starting using a *trick* when I want to stop WordPress to do things that I can't stop in a clean way: I throw an exception and catch it to continue application flow.

I'll show you an example. Note all the code here is completely untested.

First of all, let's write a custom exception:

```
class My_StopWpQueryException extends Exception {

   private $query;

   public static forQuery(WP_Query $query) {
     $instance = new static();
     $instance->query = $query;

     return $instance;
   }

   public function wpQuery() {
     return $this->query;
   }
}
```

The exception is designed to act as a sort of *DTO* to transport a query object, so that in a `catch` block you can get and use it.

Better explained with code:

```
function maybe_cached_query(WP_Query $query) {
    $cached_query = wp_cache_get($query->query_vars_hash, 'globals');
    if ($cached_query instanceof WP_Query)
       throw My_StopWpQueryException::forQuery($cached_query);
}

function cached_query_set(WP_Query $query) {
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $query;
    $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] = $query;
    // maybe some more fine-tuning here...
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', function(WP_Query $query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin()) {
        try {
           maybe_cached_query($query);
        } catch(My_StopWpQueryException $e) {
           cached_query_set($e->wpQuery());
        }
    }
});
```

This should more or less work, however, there are a lot of hooks that you are not going to fire, for example `"the_posts"` and much more... if you have code that use one of those hooks to trigger in, it will break.

You can use the `cached_query_set` function to fire some of the hooks that your theme / plugins may require.

Comment: Why doesn't work with default exception class ? It shows me an error of uncaught exception ?

Comment: It should work with standard exception and a public property, but you need to catch the standard exception if you throw it @Sumit

Comment: Well I did it just by using [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228266/prevent-comments-template-to-load-comments-php/228268#228268) example. But I get uncaught exception error. I ran the simplest example of exception but seems like `do_action` should be in `try` block.

Comment: Interesting approach that can be applied in various places in WordPress, I will keep it in mind ;-) ps:  *DTO = Data Transfer Object* ?

Comment: @birgire yes :)

Comment: @Dan ticket has been reopened again today, because skipping hooks it is causing problems already...

Comment: @gmazzap Great! I will keep watching it :)

Comment: So what happened at the end? :)

Comment: This could be updated to just reflect the new option at this point. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

This is PHP question more than a WordPress question.

As [@Mark](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/23970/mark-kaplun) commented:

> *returning from the action do not return by magic from the calling function*

That is true. Placing `return` in function mean exit the function and placing return in a PHP file mean exit the file. Do not get confused with PHP construct `exit()` :P (You might find a better answer on SO about PHP `return`).

And to answer your question

You can reduce the load of query by fetching a single column instead of full table. Like [@birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26350/birgire) did here [Remove the Homepage Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/226074/32475)

May be a better answer yet to come. I just shared that what I know :)

Comment: @Dan did you get many database hits after neutralizing the query request via the `posts_request` filter? With that + single column approach we exit `WP_Query` earlier than using the `posts_pre_query` filter.. Also watch out for the sticky posts with `posts_pre_query` but we can remove it with `$q->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', 1 );` in e.g. the example [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/226074/32475).

Comment: @birgire Look like `posts_pre_query` doesn't help. Your solution is the best so far. :) If you know how we can exit query right after `pre_get_posts`, that could be great. Thank you!

Comment: @Dan `posts_pre_query` will be available from 4.6 ;)

Comment: Another approach that comes to mind is to try extending the `WP_Query` class with a custom `get_posts()` method, with a possible early exist and that calls `parent::get_posts()`  and try to override the relevant query with it. But I don't know  if that would work or make sense with your case here ;-) @Dan

Comment: @Sumit Yeah, I have tried [git](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress) version but I can't figure out how it can completely stop `WP_Query` hitting database. :)

Comment: @birgire It's too dangerous :X

Comment: Maybe a little bit of  [Aerosmith - Livin' On The Edge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nqcL0mjMjw) could help with that ;-) @Dan

Answer (score 2):

It will be made possible in 4.6 (assuming no changes till release) with the new `posts_pre_query` filter https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36687

Comment: @Dan, this is what happens when you want to complete the thought you had before going to sleep and not reading the other answers first ;)

Comment: Bro, it's too late now. I will read those answers later ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yep it's possible depending on what you want to cache. I've done a similar thing to cache the main loop on our homepage. Essentially you can use the `posts_request` and `posts_results` to hijack the query and hit the cache instead then also use `found_posts` to correct the pagination.

Really rough example pulled from our code (untested) but you should help you get the idea:

```
<?php
/**
 * Kill the query if we have the result in the cache
 * @var [type]
 */
add_filter( 'posts_request', function( $request, $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $page = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        $key = 'homepage_query_cache_' . $page;

        if ( wp_cache_get( $key, 'cache_group' ) )
            $request = null;

    }

    return $request;
}, 10, 2 );

/**
 * Get the result from the cache and set it as the query result
 * Or add the query result to the cache if it's not there
 * @var [type]
 */
add_filter( 'posts_results', function( $posts, $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $page = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        $key = 'homepage_query_cache_' . $page;

        if ( $cached_posts = wp_cache_get( $key, 'cache_group' ) ) {
            $posts = $cached_posts;
        } else {
            wp_cache_set( $key . '_found_posts', $query->found_posts, 'cache_group', HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
            wp_cache_set( $key, $posts, 'cache_group', HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
        }
    }

    return $posts;

}, 10, 2 );

/**
 * Correct the found posts number if we've hijacked the query results
 * @var [type]
 */
add_filter( 'found_posts', function( $num, $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $page = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        $key = 'homepage_query_cache_' . $page;

        if ( $found_posts = wp_cache_get( $key . '_found_posts', 'cache_group' ) )
            $num = $found_posts;
    }

    return $num;
}, 10, 2 );
```

More here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/19crcn/best_practice_for_hijacking_main_loop_and_caching/