# How to exclude pages from the search results

Tags: php, search, forms

I wanted to exclude `pages` from the search results, and found many ways to do it, and was wondering why use `!is_admin()` or `is_main_query()` and which way would be better.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
function search_filter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
    return $query;
}
```

---

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_filter');   
function search_filter($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
    return $query;
}
```

---

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');    
function search_filter($query) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ($query->is_search) {
            $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that when we use:

```
$query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
```

then we're overriding all searchable post types, not only the `page` post type.

That may be just fine in some cases, and we're done using some of your `pre_get_posts` snippets that fit our needs.

But sometimes we don't want to hard fix it that way. Here we discuss that kind of scenarios.

**Using the register_post_type_args filter.**

When the post type isn't specified, the `WP_Query` search uses any post types that are searchable, [namely](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d92e1fb1e4ebc3d9c28821023a797f725f7af348/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L2264):

```
$in_search_post_types = get_post_types( array('exclude_from_search' => false) );
```

When we register a post type, we can set the `exclude_from_search` parameter as false to exclude it from search.

We can modify it for the `page` post type setup with:

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', function( $args, $name )
{
    // Target 'page' post type
    if( 'page' === $name )
        $args['exclude_from_search'] = true;

    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

More about `register_post_type()` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/).

**Examples**

Here are examples where the page post type would be excluded from the search, using the above filtering:

- Main query search on the front-end with

  ```
  https://example.tld?s=testing
  ```
- Secondary query like:

  ```
  $query = new WP_Query( [ 's' => 'testing' ] );
  ```
- Secondary query like:

  ```
  $query = new WP_Query( [ 's' => 'testing', 'post_type' => 'any' ] );
  ```

**Some notes on queries with pre set post types:**

Let's consider cases where the post types are fixed, like:

```
 $query = new WP_Query( [ 's' => 'testing', 'post_type' => [ 'page', 'post'] ] );
```

If the post type is set by some array `$post_type`, then we can filter the `'page'` out it with

```
if( is_array( $post_type )  && count( $post_type ) > 1 )
{
    $post_type = array_filter( 
        $post_type, 
        function( $item ) { return 'page' !== $item; } 
    );
}
```

If we don't have direct access to that array, we could use e.g. `pre_get_posts` to remove the 'page' from the post type array, with help of the `get`/`set` methods of `WP_Query`. Here's an example for the main search query on the front end:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function search_filter( \WP_Query $query )
{
    if( ! $query->is_search() || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! is_admin() )
        return;

    $post_type = $query->get( 'post_type' );

    if( is_array( $post_type )  && count( $post_type ) > 1 )
    {
        $post_type = array_filter( 
            $post_type, 
            function( $item ) { return 'page' !== $item; } 
        );
        $query->set('post_type', $post_type );
    }

} );
```

Why did we check the array count > 1 here?

That's because we should be careful to removing `'page'` from examples like:

```
 $query = new WP_Query( [ 's' => 'testing', 'post_type' => [ 'page' ] ] );

 $query = new WP_Query( [ 's' => 'testing', 'post_type' => 'page' ] );
```

as an empty array or an empty string, for the post type:

```
 $query = new WP_Query( [ 's' => 'testing', 'post_type' => [] ] );

 $query = new WP_Query( [ 's' => 'testing', 'post_type' => '' ] );
```

will fall back to the `'post'` post type.

Note that:

```
 $query = new WP_Query( [ 's' => 'testing', 'post_type' => 'page, post' ] );
```

isn't supported, as the resulting post type would be `'pagepost'`.

In these cases, where we don't have direct access to the `WP_Query` objects, we could halt the query with tricks like `'post__in' => []` or `1=0` in the search WHERE query part or even play with the  `posts_pre_query` filter or using some more advanced methods. There are plenty of answers on this site about that. [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/229722/26350) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/226065/) is what I recall at the moment.

The `null` case:

```
 $query = new WP_Query( [ 's' => 'testing', 'post_type' => null ] );
```

falls back to `'any'` post types:

Hope it helps!

**PS:**

Also note the inconsistency in your snippets, as you have both

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

and

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

It's considered an *action*, but it will not make any difference, as actions are wrapped as filters, behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I guess your first function is better approach if i want to future proof it, in case want to create `custom post types`. Just a question, are the default searchable post types the same as [post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types), or just `'pages'` and `'posts'`?

Comment: You're welcome. I think I would change the post type registration if possbile. The default searchable post types are post, page and attachment, if I recall correctly. @SilverLink

Answer (score 3):

`pre_get_posts` will run in admin as well as the frontend, you can use it to filter posts that appear to the admin users as well as frontend results. Adding `! is_admin()` will ensure that that code only affects the frontend.

`is_main_query()` will ensure that you are only affecting the query for the posts, not for example the menu items in the nav bar, or a list of posts in the sidebar. It is recommended to use that.

Let me know if this isn't clear,