# How to not load comments form on post preview?

Tags: comments, disqus

I need a way not to load the comments form when previewing a post, is there a way to achieve this? How?

If you need a reason to help:
I use disqus and it generates a url for the "discussion" the first time the comment form loads, if this is the preview then it will look something like site.com/?post_type=food&p=41009
And this is a problem because afterwards when the post is published under a real url disqus will not recognize the comments count. The only way is to manually change the discussion url. I've already contacted disqus and they say, "not a bug" if you do not want disqus to pick the preview url, don't load disqus on the preview page, the only way i know is to completely remove the comments form, so how would i go about this? Is there some sort of conditional for the preview page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick peek at the disqus plugin. This works in disabling the option before the plugin decides to print out the form.

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_disqus_active', 'wpse_conditional_disqus_load' );
function wpse_conditional_disqus_load( $disqus_active ) {
  if( is_preview() ){
    return '0';
  }

  return $disqus_active;

}
```

You could also try something like this (not tested)

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_load_disqus');
function wpse_load_disqus( $content ){
  if( is_preview() ){
    return $content;
  }

  if( is_singular() ) { // displays on all single post types. use is_single for posts only, is_page for pages only

    $content .= ?>
      // You disqus script here
    <?php ;
  }

  return $content;

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I use disqus plugin for wordpress i don't know how it works but wouldn't it conflict with this?

Comment: Oh, I thought disqus used some sort of javascript code that you pasted where you wanted the form to show. I'm afraid that while using the plugin there's not much you can do beside what the plugin is capable of doing.  And I'm not familiar with that plugin (and it would be off topic for WPSE). If you could find some sort of HTML/Javascript code in your disqus account that you could use, I would get rid of the disqus plugin and use my approach instead.

Comment: a quick google search returned this code that you could use where you want to load disqus https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/  Now if you use this approach, you would need to change the 'init' hook to where you actually want your form to load (after the content I assume).  If you tell me where you currently load your form, I could update my answer with the appropriate hook

Comment: Where do i load the comments form? below the post content. Unless i misunderstood you.

Comment: I tried the dequeue function on my theme functions.php but it had no effect on my post previews. I ended up using a dirty trick copied from your solution: On my single.php where it calls the comment form i wrapped it on an if: `if( isset( $_GET['preview'] ) == false) {
comments_template('', true); } `

I couldn't use `if( isset( $_GET['preview'] ) && $_GET['preview'] == 'false' ){` because it wouldn't affect live single posts, knowing isset is false was enough to know is not a preview page.

Please let me know if you see flaw in this! I'm no coder.

Comment: Check my updated code, I changed the check using WP is_preview() function (thanks to @birgire).  I also changed the hook timing for the dequeue function. I think it had no effect because it was called to early. If my code works, just let me know. Your solution works but you could simplify it with the is_preview() check like `if( ! is_preview() ){ comments_template( '', true ); }`. it essentially does the same thing but with WP code and it's easier to read.

Comment: yet another update, but this last one was tested and should work (at least it does for me).  Based on @birgire's suggestion, I believe it's better to check on option and return false on `is_preview() == true` . dequeuing the script wasn't working.  So now, we are forcing the option `disqus_active` to be false **before** the plugin decides to print either inline or external js, it is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one suggestion: Close the comments when *previewing*:

```
add_filter( 'template_redirect', function()
{
    if( is_preview() )
        add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' );
} );
```

This should stop the `comments_template()` from loading if it's e.g. wrapped with

```
if( comments_open() ) 
    comments_template();
```

in your theme. There's also a `comments_open()` check within `comment_form()` to prevent the form from displaying if the comments are closed.

We could also do it manually in our child theme:

```
if( ! is_preview() ) 
    comments_template();
```

*But I'm not sure though how it works with plugins like Disqus.*

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228266/prevent-comments-template-to-load-comments-php) are some very interesting suggestions on how to interfere with the loading of `comments_template()`.

PS: I noticed the the `disqus_active` option check in the `dsq_can_replace()`  function:

```
if (get_option('disqus_active') === '0'){ return false; }
```

so we might try something like:

```
add_filter( 'template_redirect', function()
{
    is_preview() && add_filter( 'pre_option_disqus_active', 
         function( $value ) { return '0'; }
    );
} );
```

but note that this is untested!