# Create Page Template by hook programatically in Functions.php in WP 5.8.1

Tags: filters, page-template

Create template as file is great. How to do that by dynamic function?
What hook, function I need to add dynamic template to dropdown in page.
If I won't have access to server files then I stuck - no template file can be provided without physical file.

Example here on old version here what works before update: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/228763/114486

This work to part when I try to select new template from dropdown.
***It won't accept*** other than physical files so I stuck. Is there something that I missing from updates of WP?

Why not other logic? I use WP with REST API as a headless content. I added rest endpoint to get template as a logic to use proper template file on frontend. Use It as a version of frontend to choose and custom fields will be align to properly show page up

Comment: Can you rephrase the wording? I'm struggling to understand your question. Are you trying to add an option to the page template selection without creating a page template file? That's not how that feature works. As the question you linked to says, the theme backend was changed, so it won't work now. If you just want to offer a selection of styles for your headless app then page templates are not the solution. Register a post meta and build a dropdown into the post editor

Comment: "Are you trying to add an option to the page template selection without creating a page template file?" Yes, I try exacly this and this as this is built for (template select, physically or virtually)
Yes, I can use new select - why existing solution not work ? maybe someone have just simple quirk. What change in backend theme that provided solution not working?

Comment: I don't know, but it changed years ago. The existing solution was never intended for _virtual_ page templates, it's just a hack written for an older version of WordPress, and probably has unintended consequences

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated to clarify what I search for