# Post Template Query with WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, single

I've seen this solution for querying pages based off of template type: [Page template query with WP_Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29918/page-template-query-with-wp-query)

I'm having trouble getting it to work with posts, that are using a "Single Post Template:" rather than a "Template Name:" definition.

Here is my code:

```
 // query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  'meta_query' => array(
     array(
     'key' => '_wp_page_template', 
     'value' => 'single-current.php'
     )
   )
));
```

Is there a different 'key' I should be using?

Something like '_wp_post_template'

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think `_wp_page_template` gets stored unless you're explicitly changing it. Can you try a query where the template is NOT `definition`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck, one possible alternative is to get all Post ID's by the custom post type.  You could try something like this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'my-custom-post',
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
   )
));
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    the_ID();
endwhile;
```

It would require you creating a custom post type, and associating posts to it.

There are ways you can associate page templates to posts, but as far as how WP_Query would work from that point with that process, I still have to learn :)

Comment: Well technically, yes, you can associate a custom template to a post if the template has `Template Post Type: post` in the header, but only these custom values get stored in `_wp_page_template`.

Comment: ahh you are right!  My bad! I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a situation where I needed to query posts in this same way. Post use the same `_wp_page_template` meta to store the template as pages.

Here are some arguments that should work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'templatename.php'
);
```

If your template is within a folder in your theme, the path will need to be included as well:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'templates/templatename.php'
);
```

You can also query for posts that use the default template:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'default'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the responses.
It turns out the site in question was actually using the "single post template" plugin, and the templates were defined like this:

```
Single Post Template: Fullwidth
Description: Like single post but without sidebar.
```

I think this was in place for a while.
I updated the templates to this:

```
Template Name: Fullwidth
Template Post Type: post
Description: Like single post but without sidebar.
```

I got rid of the extra plugin, reassigned the posts, and now my original query is working.